# Assigning PK to Link

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello i was wondering if you guys could help me;

I would like to be able to click the Edit link which takes me to edit.php and allows me to edit that result by jobRef.

jobRef is my Primary key in my database.

```
<?php
$status = 'available';
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobStatus = "' . $status . '"');

echo "<table><tr><td>Job Reference</td><td>Description</td>";
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['jobRef']."</td>","<td>".$row['jobDescription']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='edit.php?'>Edit</a></td>";   
?>
```

This is my current code i assume i have to do something like;

```
echo "<td><a href='edit.php? id=".$results['jobRef']>Edit</a></td>";
```

However this isn't working.

Comment: remove the space from between `?` and `id`.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in /srv/http/listjobs.php

Comment: echo is not well formed: use like this `echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$results['jobRef']."'>Edit</a></td>";`

Comment: echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$results['jobRef']."'>Edit</a></td>"; - Still get thrown the error & displaying the first result

Comment: you haven't fetched `$results` ?  fetch it and it'll all be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<?php
$status = 'available';
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobStatus = "' . $status . '"');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo "<table><tr><td>Job Reference</td><td>Description</td>";
foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['jobRef']."</td>","<td>".$row['jobDescription']."</td>";
  echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['jobRef']."'>Edit</a></td>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['jobRef']."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

remove the space and put the `"'` after the variable

and get the ID at edit page via `$_REQUEST` Method

thanks